# Besides instance method, static method, and class method, is there a fourth type of method in Python?

Tags: python, oop, methods

In python, there are 3 types of methods: instance method, static method, and class method. But let's look at the following example:

```
class foo:
    def inst_method(self, *args, **kwargs): pass

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls, *args, **kwargs): pass

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(*args, **kwargs): pass

    def unknown_method(*args, **kwargs):
        print('What? ')

    def another_unknown():
        print('What??? ')

foo.unknown_method()      # OK
foo().unknown_method()    # OK

foo.another_unknown()     # OK
foo().another_unknown()   # !!!
```

Grammatically, the definition of **unknown_method** is valid and it can be invoked on the class. But which type does this method belong to?

---

Thanks to the answers I have received, it is for sure that unknown_method is still an instance method because self is just an optional name; it can be any other names.

But what about another_unknown? It can only be invoked on the class, not on an instance.

Comment: try and call it as `foo.unknown_method()` I believe it will give you an erreor that you need an instance (ie its an instance method)

Comment: Strictly speaking, the "static method" is just a plain old function.  There are only really *two* types:  bound methods and unbound methods.  Read up on the "descriptor protocol" for the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still a regular instance method. You can demonstrate this like so:

```
>>> class Foo:
        mystery_method(*args, **kwargs):
            print(*args, sep = '\n')
>>> f = Foo(1, 'bar', None)
>>> f.mystery_method()
<__main__.Foo object at XXXX>
1
bar
None
```

As you can see, we only passed in 3 arguments, but four arguments have been printed. The first member of `*args` has been bound to the object instance, just as with any other regular instance method.

The usage of `self` as the first argument is just a convention.

The other method example you gave (with no arguments) will just raise an exception because Python will try to pass the class instance to the method, but the method accepts zero arguments. It is still an instance method.

Comment: I agree with your main point. But it seems that there is a tiny difference when you call them. Since a typical instance method defines its first parameter as a required parameter (self), when you invoke it, you must pass an instance. But since you define all parameters of mystery_method optional, you don't need to pass any instance argument. I.e., you can invoke Foo.mystery_method(), and a typical instance method must be invoked as Foo.inst_method(instance) or Foo().inst_method(), but you can never call it Foo.inst_method().

Comment: @Peng As Joran Beasley pointed out, the real stipulation is between bound and unbound. That is the concept your example exemplifies.

Answer (score 2):

`self` is just a label. The first argument passed into these functions is always the instance, whether you call it `self` or not. You could call it `this` or `blerg`, but the first argument passed to the function will always be the instance.

Short version: no, there's no `unknown_method`. It's just another type of `inst_method`.

---

**EDIT**

`other_unknown` won't work at all because one argument will be passed in. You'll get a `TypeError`.

Comment: Sorry I edited your answer instead of mine! Never done that before.